# ShinyApps Datatable Fixedheader with ScrollY

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

My shiny application holds a table of 20-50 rows, and the users requested a fixed header.

After adding the fixed header we have scrolling issues though, if you scroll down +/- 5 lines it pops you back up to the top and this just keeps repeating.

I set my datatable up as follows:

```
    DT::datatable(data,
              caption = htmltools::tags$caption(style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center; color:orange; font-size:200% ;','Order Acceptance Requests'),
              rownames = FALSE,
              extensions = c("FixedHeader"),#, "Scroller"),
              options = list(paging = FALSE,
                             searching = FALSE,
                             columnDefs = ColSorting,
                             #deferRender = TRUE,
                             autoWidth = TRUE,
                             ordering = TRUE,
                             info = FALSE,
                             fixedHeader = TRUE,
                             #scroller = TRUE,
                             ScrollY = "200px",
                             pageLength = -1

              ))
```

I've tried playing around with Scroller but it doesn't help me solve it (or I haven't figured out how to solve it using Scroller).

I know that there used to be compatibility issues, but according to https://datatables.net/download/compatibility it should now work together.

Comment: To help you I would need to see a bit more of the shiny UI. I use DT with ScrollY without issues. The problem is specific to your page. Render this datatable in a plain shiny `basicPage()` and see if you have the same problem. If you do, post it and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Additionally, `columnDefs = ColSorting,` gives an error. I commented out the columnDefs and do not see a problem when I pace this in a plain page. Works as expected. Tested in  Brave and Chrome with a data frame with 1000 rows